# Can't parse xml properly with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, lxml

I'm trying to scrape this page: https://www.france24.com/en/europe/rss

My code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

xml = urlopen("https://www.france24.com/en/europe/rss")
data = xml.read()
text = data.decode('utf-8')
bs = BeautifulSoup(text, "lxml")
items = bs.find("rss").find("channel").find_all("item")
for n, item in enumerate(items):
    print(f"\n{n+1} - {item.find('title').get_text()}")
    print(item.find("pubDate"))
    print(item.find("description").get_text().replace("\n", ""))
    print(item.find("link").get_text())
```

The structure I'm interested in:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" version="2.0">
    <channel>
        <lastBuildDate>Fri, 23 Apr 2021 06:08:56 GMT</lastBuildDate>
        <item>
            <category>Europe</category>
            <title>French fishermen seek to block British shipments in Brexit protest</title>
            <link>https://www.france24.com/en/europe/20210423-french-fishermen-seek-to-block-british-shipments-in-brexit-protest</link>
            <description>
French trawlermen angered by the slow issuance of licenses to fish inside British waters after Brexit on Thursday blocked lorries carrying UK-landed fish as they arrived in Boulogne-sur-Mer, Europe’s largest seafood processing centre.
</description>
            <media:thumbnail url="https://s.france24.com/media/display/70e354e8-a3e7-11eb-a6eb-005056bf87d6/w:1024/p:16x9/Brexit%20fishermen%20protest.jpg" />
            <enclosure url="https://s.france24.com/media/display/70e354e8-a3e7-11eb-a6eb-005056bf87d6/w:1024/p:16x9/Brexit%20fishermen%20protest.jpg" type="image/jpeg" length="0" />
            <guid isPermaLink="false">cadc08aa-a3e7-11eb-91c0-005056bff4a8</guid>
            <pubDate>Fri, 23 Apr 2021 03:55:46 GMT</pubDate>
            <source url="https://s.france24.com/media/display/70e354e8-a3e7-11eb-a6eb-005056bf87d6/w:1024/p:16x9/Brexit%20fishermen%20protest.jpg">© Denis Charlet, AFP</source>
            <dc:creator>NEWS WIRES</dc:creator>
        </item>
```

The output:

```
1 - French fishermen seek to block British shipments in Brexit protest
None
French trawlermen angered by the slow issuance of licenses to fish inside British waters after Brexit on Thursday blocked lorries carrying UK-landed fish as they arrived in Boulogne-sur-Mer, Europe’s largest seafood processing centre.

(...)
```

As you can see the pubDate and the link were not printed.

Here's the result of `print(bs)` to see how BS parsed the xml (formatted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html>
    <body>
        <rss version="2.0" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/">
            <channel>
                <lastbuilddate>Fri, 23 Apr 2021 06:08:56 GMT</lastbuilddate>
                <item>
                    <category>Europe</category>
                    <title>French fishermen seek to block British shipments in Brexit protest</title>
                    <link />
                    https://www.france24.com/en/europe/20210423-french-fishermen-seek-to-block-british-shipments-in-brexit-protest
                    <description>
French trawlermen angered by the slow issuance of licenses to fish inside British waters after Brexit on Thursday blocked lorries carrying UK-landed fish as they arrived in Boulogne-sur-Mer, Europe’s largest seafood processing centre.
</description>
                    <media:thumbnail url="https://s.france24.com/media/display/70e354e8-a3e7-11eb-a6eb-005056bf87d6/w:1024/p:16x9/Brexit%20fishermen%20protest.jpg"></media:thumbnail>
                    <enclosure length="0" type="image/jpeg" url="https://s.france24.com/media/display/70e354e8-a3e7-11eb-a6eb-005056bf87d6/w:1024/p:16x9/Brexit%20fishermen%20protest.jpg"></enclosure>
                    <guid ispermalink="false">cadc08aa-a3e7-11eb-91c0-005056bff4a8</guid>
                    <pubdate>Fri, 23 Apr 2021 03:55:46 GMT</pubdate>
                    <source url="https://s.france24.com/media/display/70e354e8-a3e7-11eb-a6eb-005056bf87d6/w:1024/p:16x9/Brexit%20fishermen%20protest.jpg">© Denis Charlet, AFP</source>
                    <dc:creator>NEWS WIRES</dc:creator>
                </item>
```

Note **pubdate** and **link /**.

I fail to see what the problem is. Any opinions as to why it is being parsed incorrectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the `xml` parser:

```
bs = BeautifulSoup(text, "xml")
```

Here's the output I get for the first item:

```
1 - Without licenses to fish in British waters, French trawlermen block deliveries of UK-landed fish
<pubDate>Fri, 23 Apr 2021 03:55:46 GMT</pubDate>
French trawlermen angered by the slow issuance of licenses to fish inside British waters after Brexit on Thursday blocked lorries carrying UK-landed fish as they arrived in Boulogne-sur-Mer, Europe’s largest seafood processing centre.
https://www.france24.com/en/europe/20210423-french-fishermen-seek-to-block-british-shipments-in-brexit-protest
```

Answer (score 1):

For the pubDate :

In the Xml that is parsed with BS, the balise `pubDate` become `pubdate` or in your code you are looking for `pubDate`

Maybe you can try this.